# Search Bar filter listview items

Tags: java, android

I'm wanting to put a search bar to act as a filter for the data displayed in the listview.I could not find any examples that do something like that.
If someone can show me how I can do this or demonstrate an example I am very grateful.

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

         //the GridView
    GridView lv;
         Bitmap  bitmap;
        //The list that contains the menuitems (sort)
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        View btnLoadMore;
        Spinner spinner;

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        //The list that contains the wallappers
        ArrayList<Wallpaper> productsList;

        //The adapter of the WallPaperList
        WallPaperAdapter adapter;

        private final String baseurl = AppConstant.BASE_URL;
        String list_url;

        // url to get all products list
        private String url_all_products = baseurl + "get_all_products.php";
        private String get_tag_products = baseurl + "get_tag_products.php";

        // Flag for current page
        int current_page = 0;
        int max_pages;


        // Prevent loading more items to the GridView twice
        boolean isLoading;

        //
        String sort_order;
        String tag;

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_PAGE = "page";
        private static final String TAG_ORDER = "order";
        private static final String TAG_TAG = "tag";
        private static final String TAG_THUMBURL = "url";
        private static final String TAG_TOTAL_PAGE = "total_page";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;

        // listener for sort order
        private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

                Log.v("Selected: ", Integer.toString(position));
                    if (position == 0){
                        sort_order = "latest";
                    } else if (position == 1){
                        sort_order = "popular";
                    } else if (position == 2){
                        sort_order = "oldest";
                    } else if (position == 3){
                        sort_order = "alphabet";
                    }



                    //"resetting the GridView"
                    productsList.clear();

                    if (adapter != null){
                        adapter.clear();
                    }

                    current_page = 0;

                    isLoading = false;

                    //TODO footerview is not visible

                    ConnectivityManager cm =
                            (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                     if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                            new InitialLoadGridView().execute();
                     } else {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGridActivity.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     }
                //}
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        };

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listfragment, null);
           lv = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
           setRetainInstance(true);
           setHasOptionsMenu(true);



           return view;
       }
       *@Override
       public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

           inflater.inflate(R.menu.pesquisa, menu);
           super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

                   //Pega o Componente.  
           SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
                   .getActionView();
           //Define um texto de ajuda:
                   mSearchView.setQueryHint("teste");

           // exemplos de utilização:

           return;

       }*
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            ActionBar actions = getActivity().getActionBar();
            actions.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            // Adapter
            SpinnerAdapter spinadapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.actions,
                //android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                R.layout.actionbar_spinner_item);


            Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
            navigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinadapter);
            // Here you set navigation listener
            navigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener); 
            actions.setCustomView(navigationSpinner);

            if (getActivity().getActionBar().getCustomView().getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                getActivity().getActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            actions.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

            //ListFragment is created, so let's clear the imageloader cache
            ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();

            // Arraylist for GridView
            productsList = new ArrayList<Wallpaper>();

            //initialize the footer so it can be used
            btnLoadMore = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.footerview, null);


           if ((getResources().getString(R.string.ad_visibility).equals("0"))){
                // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
                AdView adView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
           }

           //TODO Implement and replace old
           lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

               int currentVisibleItemCount;
               int currentScrollState;

               public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                   this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
               }

               public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                   this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                   this.isScrollCompleted();
               }

               private void isScrollCompleted() {
                   if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                       /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
                       /*** do the work for load more date! ***/
                       if(!isLoading){
                           isLoading = true;
                           if (max_pages != current_page){
                               new loadMoreGridView().execute();
                           } else {
                               Log.v("INFO", "Not loading more items because everything is already showing");
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           });


           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    //String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();

                    String pid = productsList.get(position).getPid();


                    boolean singlepane = MainActivity.getPane();
                    if(singlepane== true){
                        /*
                         * The second fragment not yet loaded. 
                         * Load DetailFragment by FragmentTransaction, and pass 
                         * data from current fragment to second fragment via bundle.
                         */

                        DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
                        Fragment myListFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragment");
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("TAG_PID",pid);
                        detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                                R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

                        //This could use some improvement, but it works, hide current fragment, show new one
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(myListFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.phone_container, detailFragment);
                        //fragmentTransaction.show(myDetailFragment);


                        /*
                         * Add this transaction to the back stack. 
                         * This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is 
                         * committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off 
                         * the stack.
                         */
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    }

                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * Async Task that send a request to url
         * Gets new list view data
         * Appends to list view
         * */
        private class loadMoreGridView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

                        // increment current page
                        current_page += +1;

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PAGE, Integer.toString(current_page)));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ORDER, (sort_order)));

                        if (tag != null){
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TAG, (tag)));
                        } else {
                            list_url = url_all_products;
                        }

                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(list_url, "GET", params);

                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                        try {
                            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // products found
                                // Getting Array of Products
                                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                                // looping through All Products
                                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                                    String thumburl = c.getString(TAG_THUMBURL);
                                    // adding items to arraylist
                                    productsList.add(new Wallpaper(name, thumburl, id));
                                }
                            } else {
                                // no products found

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                //OUTDATED - Listview seems to automatically keep up with the position
                                //get GridView current position - used to maintain scroll position
                                //int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                                // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                //OUTDATED - Setting new scroll position
                                //lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

                                if (current_page == max_pages){
                                    adapter.RemoveFooterView();
                                } else {
                                    adapter.setFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                return (null);
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                // closing progress dialog
                isLoading = false;

            }
        }

        /**
         * Async Task that send a request to url
         * Gets new list view data
         * Appends to list view
         * */
        private class InitialLoadGridView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                        getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.wait));
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ORDER, (sort_order)));

                try { tag = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("TAG"); } catch (Exception e){}

                if (tag != null){
                    list_url = get_tag_products;
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TAG, (tag)));
                } else {
                    list_url = url_all_products;
                }
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(list_url, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    max_pages = json.getInt(TAG_TOTAL_PAGE);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String thumburl = c.getString(TAG_THUMBURL);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding items to arraylist
                            productsList.add(new Wallpaper(name, thumburl, id));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // no products found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                                // Getting adapter
                                adapter = new WallPaperAdapter(
                                getActivity(), productsList);

                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                                current_page = 0;

                                if (current_page == max_pages){
                                    adapter.RemoveFooterView();
                                } else {
                                    adapter.setFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                return (null);
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                // closing progress dialog
                pDialog.dismiss();

                lv.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        //check if last item is visible, in that case, load some more items
                        if (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() == lv.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
                                lv.getChildAt(lv.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= lv.getHeight() )
                        {
                            if(!isLoading){
                                isLoading = true;
                                if (max_pages != current_page){
                                    new loadMoreGridView().execute();
                                    Log.v("INFO", "Last Item Visible and more available so loading more");
                                } else {
                                    Log.v("INFO", "Already showing max pages");
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.v("INFO", "Last Item Not Visible, not loading more");
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
            super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
            Fragment myListFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragment");
            if (myListFragment != null && myListFragment.isVisible()) {
                 //VISIBLE! =)
                 Log.d("STATE", "Just became visible!");
                 getActivity().getActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Context context){
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    dp, 
                    resources.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
        }

        public interface MyFragInterface {
            public void needsHide();
        }

        public static boolean isInVisible(GridView scrollView, View view, Rect region, boolean relative)
        {
            int top = scrollView.getScrollY() + region.top;
            int bottom = scrollView.getScrollY() + region.bottom;

            if(!relative)
            {
                // If given region is not relative to scrollView 
                // i.e 0,0 does not point to first child left and top
                top -= scrollView.getTop();
                bottom -= scrollView.getTop();
            }

            Rect rect = new Rect(region);
            rect.top = top;
            rect.bottom = bottom;
            Rect childRegion = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());

            return Rect.intersects(childRegion, region);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AutoCompleteTextView for search bar is the simplest way for me, following is a sample code,hope that will help.

Layout Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/search_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_text"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/countries_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextview;
    ListView capitalList;
    ArrayAdapter searchTextviewAdapter;
    private View rootView;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(" Letsgomo");
        searchTextview= (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        capitalList= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
        searchTextviewAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Constants.capitals);
        searchTextview.setAdapter(searchTextviewAdapter);
        ArrayAdapter capitalAdapter= (ArrayAdapter) searchTextview.getAdapter();
        capitalList.setAdapter(capitalAdapter);
        capitalList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }
```

}